# zend framework 2 How do i link a file in the controller (What is the path)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How do I link a file in the controller

```
$OpenuUserPersonalFile = fopen("/ZendEbayApp/data/usersinformationin/userPersonal.txt", "r");

echo fgets($OpenuUserPersonalFile) . "<br />";

fclose($OpenuUserPersonalFile);
```

Would this be corrent?

Here is how i link a file in my layout `/ZendEbayApp/public/css/MainPageLayout.css`

This is where my controller is: `\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using the ZF2 Skeleton application, you'll notice that public/index.php contains a line like:

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

That's changes the directory to the root of your project.

So to reference the file in your example, you'd simply do:

```
$fp = fopen('data/usersinformationin/file.txt', 'r');
```

Comment: So how would i link a file in the controller and yes i am using the ZF2 Skeleton application. Will i have to add chdir(dirname(__DIR__)); to the controller? I just checked and this code does not work in the public/index.php folder ------ $OpenuUserPersonalFile = fopen("data/usersinformationin/userPersonal.txt", "r");
        echo fgets($OpenuUserPersonalFile) . "<br />";
        fclose($OpenuUserPersonalFile);

Comment: No need to do chdir(dirname(__DIR__)) in the controller.  It's already been done in index.php.  As long as you don't do any chdir() stuff in your module bootstraps, etc, it will still be in effect throughout the request.